# reCAPTCHA with Content Security Policy

Tags: recaptcha, content-security-policy

I'm trying to make reCAPTCHA work along with a strict Content Security Policy. This is the basic version I have, which works correctly:

HTML

```
<script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
```

HTTP Headers

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' www.google.com www.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src www.google.com;
```

However, I would like to get rid of the `unsafe-inline` in the `style-src` section. On the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#im-using-content-security-policy-csp-on-my-website-how-can-i-configure-it-to-work-with-recaptcha), it is written that:

> We recommend using the nonce-based approach documented with CSP3. Make sure to include your nonce in the reCAPTCHA api.js script tag, and we'll handle the rest.

But I can't make it work... This is what I tried:

HTML

```
<script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' nonce="{NONCE}" async defer></script>
```

HTTP Headers

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https: 'nonce-{NONCE}'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-{NONCE}'; child-src www.google.com;
```

And this is the error I get on Chrome 53:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https: 'nonce-{NONCE}'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-MammJ3J+TGIHdHxYsGLjD6DzRU0ZmxXKZ2DvTePAF0o='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: This answer is now outdated and no longer relevant.

---

I no not believe reCAPTCHA supports CSP without allowing inline styles. I found [this open issue](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/107) in the reCAPTCHA Github repository.

[This sample page with reCAPTCHA using CSP](https://csp-experiments.appspot.com/recaptcha-nonce-test) works because it does not define `style-src` or `default-src`. An inspection of the page's DOM reveals this inserted div:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdOLRgTAAAAAPYECt9KLIL_LLwOuuuHAUw7QUTm">
    <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
        <div>
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6LdOLRgTAAAAAPYECt9KLIL_LLwOuuuHAUw7QUTm&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9jc3AtZXhwZXJpbWVudHMuYXBwc3BvdC5jb206NDQz&amp;hl=en&amp;v=r20160926121436&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=g72al0v10dxg" title="recaptcha widget" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="undefined"></iframe>
        </div>
        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

The inline style for `textarea` evaluates to `MammJ3J+TGIHdHxYsGLjD6DzRU0ZmxXKZ2DvTePAF0o=` as determined by:

```
echo -n "width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; " | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | base64
```

This matches the hash indicated in your error message. However, including the hash in `style-src` does not work for inline styles in Chrome [per this open bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546106). It appears this will be supported with `unsafe-hashed-attributes` which as far as I can tell hasn't made it to a Chrome release.

For what it's worth, adding the hash makes it work in Firefox.

Comment: Very useful links to related issues in other issue trackers!

Comment: also sandbox value affects this

Comment: This answer is outdated, reCaptcha now supports CSP.

Answer (score 12):

The reCAPTCHA service has been updated so `style-src 'unsafe-inline'` is not required anymore. Below HTML and HTTP headers should work per [this](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/107) closed issue:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=site-key" nonce="{NONCE}"></script>
```

HTTP Header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'nonce-{NONCE}'; img-src www.gstatic.com; frame-src www.google.com; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'none';
```

Comment: Works if you add www.google.com also in script-src

Comment: worked for me when added https://www.gstatic.com inside script-src

Comment: @Hemant gstatic.com or www.google.com hosts libraries that make you completely XSS vulnerable, do not use it in script-src

Answer (score -5):

use below code in the web.config file for ASp.Net applications.

```
<child-src>
      <add source="www.google.com"/>
```