# CSP causing google recaptcha to throw error: can't load from origin null?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recaptcha, same-origin-policy, content-security-policy

Exact error:

> recaptcha__en.js:205 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct
>   'Worker': Script at
>   'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/webworker.js?hl=en&v=v1520231465640'
>   cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.

If I remove CPS completely this error goes away, also note I'm localhost. Not running on a file system

CPS policy looks like this

```
scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'https://*.gstatic.com/', 'https://*.google.com/', 'https://*.googleapis.com'],
styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'https://*.gstatic.com/', 'https://*.google.com/', 'https://*.googleapis.com'],
fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.gstatic.com/', 'https://*.google.com/', 'https://*.googleapis.com'],
imgSrc: ["'self'", 'data:', 'https://*.gstatic.com/', 'https://*.google.com/', 'https://*.googleapis.com'],
sandbox: ['allow-forms', 'allow-scripts'],
reportUri: '/report-violation',
objectSrc: ["'none'"],
upgradeInsecureRequests: false,
workerSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.gstatic.com/', 'https://*.google.com/', 'https://*.googleapis.com', '*'],
frameSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.gstatic.com/', 'https://*.google.com/', 'https://*.googleapis.com']
```

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853162/recaptcha-with-content-security-policy/39914043#39914043

Comment: removed sandbox attribute and it works