# Google ReCaptcha CSP eval violation despite of correct nonce?

Tags: recaptcha, content-security-policy

I have the following CSP header:

> script-src 'self' *.google.com *.googletagmanager.com *.google-analytics.com 'nonce-XXXXXX'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com; img-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com/; object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' wss:; frame-ancestors 'none'; report-uri XXXX;

The site is currently running under

> https://127.0.0.1/test/

The script:

```
<script async defer src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" 
 nonce="XXXXXX"></script>
```

Upon loading the page that contains the captcha or submitting the form, I got a bunch of reports, containing the following error:

```
blocked-uri eval
column-number   8
document-uri    https://127.0.0.1/test/
line-number 27
original-policy script-src 'nonce-06119715-2ed2-42ae-99b1-edf58ab76283' 'nonce-8834c239-fa22-4e70-965d-8134dc20ae4e'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com/; object-src 'none'; report-uri https://127.0.0.1/test/csp-report
referrer    
source-file blob:https://127.0.0.1/47fba858-3af0-4468-a1fe-32e077414fc1
violated-directive  script-src
```

If I allow 'unsafe-inline', the reports disappear. What am I doing wrong?

I am following the instructions on the page [reCAPTCHA with Content Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853162/recaptcha-with-content-security-policy), but without success.

Comment: Have you tried adding `unsafe-eval` instead of `unsafe-inline`? What happens then?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it solves the problem. On the other hand, it makes no sense to add something like this to the CSP. The exact point of CSP is to prevent these kind of script executions.

Comment: Ok, but then your problem is not connected to inline, it's connected to the async call which probably doesn't return with the correct nonce.

Comment: What we'll have to do a lot is to raise issues with plugins and libraries to let them know they should refactor their code to avoid `eval(string)`.

Comment: Also, the problem in only present in Firefox. I think that this might be a browser-related bug.