# How to implement google reCaptcha without inline script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

**Desired Behaviour**

Incorporate reCaptcha JavaScript code in my webpack bundled js file, rather than via inline script tags.

**Actual Behaviour**

I am getting this error in Chrome dev tools:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined

**What I've Tried**

The following `inline` implementation works and I have been using [these docs for reference](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display).

However I had to add `unsafe-inline` to my `script-src` Content Security Policy in order to allow the inline script to run.  More specifically, this was required to implement [explicit rendering](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render) via the `onLoadCallback` function.

Google has an [FAQ about CSP and reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#im-using-content-security-policy-csp-on-my-website.-how-can-i-configure-it-to-work-with-recaptcha), but it only applies to [automatic rendering](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render), where there is no callback function or [defined parameters](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param).

I'd prefer not to have to use inline scripts.

**index.html**

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': '******',
            'size': 'compact'
        });
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="g-recaptcha"></div>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try adding the JS to my `entry.js` file like this (to stop using inline script):

**index.html**

```html
<head>
    <script type="module" src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="g-recaptcha"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**entry.js**

```js
const onloadCallback = () => {
    grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
        'sitekey': '******',
        'size': 'compact',
        'data-callback': 'ok-you-can-submit-the-form',
        'data-expired-callback': 'you-have-to-click-recaptcha-again',
        'data-error-callback': 'something-went-wrong-please-try-again'
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    onloadCallback();

}
```

I get the error in Chrome dev tools:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined

So I am guessing this is because `bundle.js` does not have any knowledge of the recaptcha script, or its related variables, defined in the `<head>` section.

How can I implement google reCaptcha without using the inline script paradigm?

**Edit**

I think Google's suggestion to use a [nonce-based approach](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#im-using-content-security-policy-csp-on-my-website.-how-can-i-configure-it-to-work-with-recaptcha) (also suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890878)) only works if you are doing  [automatic rendering](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render) (where only a `<script src="****">` tag is required).

If you are using [explicit rendering](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render) as I am, which requires definition of a callback function inline, then i don't think the nonce approach works.

Comment: You need to use a proper npm build for that, the usual recaptcha CDN build won't work with webpack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just posting what worked for me in the end.

Use [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3).

`index.html` head:

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=*******"></script>
```

on click event:

```js
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('*******', { action: 'submit_entry' }).then(function(token) {
        parameters.token = token;
        ajax_api_entries_post(parameters);
    });
});
```

verification of google token from server:

```js
var token = req.body.token;
var url = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret_key}&response=${token}`;
var response = await fetch(url);
var response_json = await response.json();

var score = response_json.score;

// see: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#interpreting_the_score
if (score >= 0.5) { ...
```

[helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) configuration:

```js
app.use(
    helmet({
        contentSecurityPolicy: {
            directives: {
                defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
                scriptSrc: ["'self'", "https://maps.googleapis.com", "https://www.google.com", "https://www.gstatic.com"],
                connectSrc: ["'self'", "https://some-domain.com", "https://some.other.domain.com"],
                styleSrc: ["'self'", "fonts.googleapis.com", "'unsafe-inline'"],
                fontSrc: ["'self'", "fonts.gstatic.com"],
                imgSrc: ["'self'", "https://maps.gstatic.com", "https://maps.googleapis.com", "data:", "https://another-domain.com"],
                frameSrc: ["'self'", "https://www.google.com"]
            }
        },
    })
);
```