# ReCAPTCHA2 script load error due to Security Policy directive

Tags: angular6, recaptcha, content-security-policy

In my `Angular` application, I am getting the following error when I am trying to use `reCAPTCHA2`.

```
vendor.js:184374 Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=ngx_captcha_onload_callback&render=explicit&hl=en' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I am using this `Angular` variant - https://enngage.github.io/ngx-captcha/

How can I solve the problem? My current security policy is `contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;img-src 'self' data: ; worker-src blob:"`

I don't want to open the web application to all types of scripts.

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853162/recaptcha-with-content-security-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying it like this:

```
contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;img-src 'self' data: ; worker-src blob:"
```

I've just added:

```
 https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/
```

Comment: Thanks. I added `script-src https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ ` and ` frame-src https://www.google.com/recaptcha/` which is very close to your answer. I suppose your's will work as well.

Comment: Hi, you miss `www` and trailing slash, it [should be](https://csplite.com/csp/test298/) `frame-src www.google.com/recaptcha/` (`/recaptcha/` is a folder name, not file name). May be it's more safe to use both www and non-www variants simultaneously.